# gdal_grid - fails to find layer and field

Tags: raster, gdal, dem

I'm using gdal_grid for the first time and get this issue:

```
gdal_grid -zfield field_3 -l layer0 OLEX-LAT-190952014.vrt OLEX-LAT-190952014.tiff
ERROR 1: Failed to find layer 'layer0' on datasource 'OLEX-LAT-190952014.short.csv'.
Failed to find field field_3 on layer layer0, skipping.
```

Here is what my vrt file looks like:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
<OGRVRTLayer name="layer0">
<SrcDataSource>OLEX-LAT-190952014.short.csv</SrcDataSource>
<GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
<LayerSRS>EPSG:25832</LayerSRS>
<GeometryField separator=" " encoding="PointFromColumns" x="field_1" y="field_2" z="field_3"/>
</OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

And my data file:

```
field_1,field_2,field_3
6932193.2570,377160.7010,-33.1300
6932194.6430,377162.4380,-32.6600
```

1. The first error mesage indicates that gdal_grid looks for a layer in the csv file - but how can a csv file contain a layer?
2. The next error message indicates that gdal_grid has read the csv file and can't find field_3 although it is clearly there?

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

GDAL version 1.10.1

Comment: Try `ogrinfo OLEX-LAT-190952014.vrt`. Report will list the layer names which are found from the vrt (and csv). `ogrinfo -al -so` will list the attribute names.

Comment: Thanks, ogrinfo didn't give any error messages. I figured it out, though - see below.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ogrinfo` as a handy debugging tool. I see:

```
$ ogrinfo OLEX-LAT-190952014.vrt
INFO: Open of `OLEX-LAT-190952014.vrt'
      using driver `VRT' successful.
1: layer0ERROR 1: Failed to find layer 'layer0' on datasource 'OLEX-LAT-190952014.short.csv'. (Point)
```

According to [the documentation](http://www.gdal.org/drv_vrt.html), `SrcLayer` is optional, but should be defined (unless in `SrcSQL`). Add this after `SrcDataSource`:

```
<SrcLayer>OLEX-LAT-190952014.short</SrcLayer>
```

Alternatively, use `OLEX-LAT-190952014.short` for the layer name (line 2) in place of `layer0`.

Comment: Using the same name for .csv, .vrt and layer is always a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. What worked out in the end was to rename everyting to have exactly the same name - the layer, the csv file and the vrt file - all of them "OLEX-LAT-190952014_short". The <SrcLayer> had no effect.

The output tiff is blank though?

The suffix "short" is for testing using only 1000 points, the real data contains nearly 2 million points. I'm afraid that x and y fields have been swapped in the csv file.

Comment: Indeed, the first field in the csv file was Y/northing. I made it work by chaning the labels in the vrt file to '<GeometryField separator=" " encoding="PointFromColumns" x="easting" y="northing" z="z"/>' and the field names accordingly in the csv file. It looks correct now when I add it to my map!